# React Native & VS Code - breakpoints not being hit

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code, adb

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native) to install the VS code extension and enable React Native debugging. Now when I hit the run button my app builds and deploys in the Android emulator but breakpoints are not being hit.
The doc. has a 'known issue' around breakpoints not being hit but only has a resolution for TypeScript, which I'm not using.

What do I need to do to get the debugger in VS Code to break on breakpoints in my React Native app?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? Having same issue.